# Allowing hypen based words to be tokenized in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I have the following mapping for a field `name` that will hold products name for ecommerce.

```
   'properties': {
       'name': {
           'type': 'text',
           'analyzer': 'standard',
           'fields': {
                'english': {
                'type': 'text',
                'analyzer': 'english'
            },
        }
    },
```

Assuming that I have the following string to be indexed/searched.

**A pack of 3 T-shirts**

Both of the analyerzs are producing terms [t, shirts], [t, shirt] respectively.

This gives me the problem of not getting any result when a user types **"mens tshirts"**

How can i get the term in the inverted index like [t, shirts, shirt, tshirt', tshirts]

I tried to look into Stemmers exclusions but I couldn't find any thing to deal with hyphens. Also i will be helpful if a more generic solution is found rather than doing exclusions manually. Because there could be many possiblities which i don't know now e.g `emails, e-mails`

Answer (score 1):

whitespace tokenizer could do the job

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "text": "The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone."
}
```

will produce

```
[ The, 2, QUICK, Brown-Foxes, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog's, bone. ]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17725026)

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Comment: Hi, this could help me when people search ```t-shirts```. What i am more looking for is ```tshirts``` so in your example term needed would be `[brownfoxes]`

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution which i guess could help me achieving the desired results. However, I would still like to see if there is some good and recommended approach for this problem.

Basically I will use multi fields for this problem where the first analyzer will be standard and the second will be my custom.

According to Elasticsearch documentation, `chars_filters` happens before `tokenizer`. So the idea is to remove `-` with a empty character which will make `t-shirts` to `tshirt`. Hence the tokenizer will token the whole term as `tshirts` in invertded index.

```
GET _analyze
{
   "tokenizer": "standard",
   "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      {"type": "stop", "stopwords": "_english_"}
   ],
   "char_filter" : [
       "html_strip", 
       {"type": "mapping", "mappings": ["- => "]}
    ],
   "text": "these are t-shirts <table>"
}
```

will give the following tokens

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "tshirts",
         "start_offset": 10,
         "end_offset": 18,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```